# Intellij Idea highlighter

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, ide

I am looking for some kind of highlighter plug in for Idea Intellij. Some like paper highlighter. I mean I want to highlight not only a variable or a function or class but a selected piece of code. A plug-in like this will make my life easier. [image]

Comment: Did you find a plugin like this? It's something I wish I could do from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok for you to highlight only complete code blocks at a time (in other words, highlight the complete variable, statement, class, or whatever), you could look at the `PsiViewer` plugin.

It is originally meant for viewing the PsiTree - the structure of your java code, but it also has a handy highlighter feature, which is very similar to what you describe.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/227

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. Thanks any way.